# how to make user input vowels in online

Tags: java

I have some trouble with my program. I have already solved the necessary things that must appear in the console but not the goal for the program output. This is my work, Java control structure-Looping.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sad= new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int input=0,lowercasea=1,uppercaseA=1,lowercasee=1,uppercaseE=1,
            lowercasei=1,uppercaseI=1,lowercaseo=1,uppercaseO=1,
            lowercaseu=1,uppercaseU=1,counter=0;
    char vowel=0;
    System.out.print("how many vowels do you want to input? ");
    input=sad.nextInt();
    
    while(input!=counter) { 
    System.out.print("enter the vowel: ");
        vowel= sad.next().charAt(0);
        
    System.out.println("you enter: "+vowel);
    if (input==vowel) 
        System.out.println("");
    
    else if (vowel=='a') {
        System.out.println("count of lowercase a: "+lowercasea);
    lowercasea++;}
    else if(vowel=='A') {
        System.out.println("count of Uppercase A: "+uppercaseA);
    uppercaseA++;}
    else if(vowel=='e') {
        System.out.println("count for lowercase e: "+lowercasee);
        lowercasee++;}
    else if(vowel=='E') {
        System.out.println("count for Uppercase E: "+uppercaseE);
        uppercaseE++;}
    else if (vowel=='i') {
        System.out.println("count for lowercase i: "+lowercasei);
        lowercasei++;}
    else if(vowel=='I') {
        System.out.println("count for uppercase I: "+uppercaseI);
        uppercaseI++;}
    else if (vowel=='o') {
        System.out.println("count for lowercase o: "+lowercaseo);
    lowercaseo++;}
    else if(vowel=='O') {
        System.out.println("count for uppercase O: "+uppercaseO);
    uppercaseO++;}
    else if(vowel=='u') {
        System.out.println("count for lowercase u: "+lowercaseu);
    lowercaseu++;}
    else if (vowel=='U') {
        System.out.println("count for uppercase U: "+uppercaseU);}
        }
    counter++;
    }
}
```

and here is an example of how output must be

```
how many vowels do you want to input? 6
enter vowel: a
enter vowel: E
enter vowel: i
enter vowel: I
enter vowel: a
enter vowel: a
you entered: a E i I a a
count of lowercase a: 3time(s)
count of uppercase E: 1 time(s)
count of lowercase i: 1time(s)
count of uppercase I: 1time(s)
```

Comment: Why are you not using `Hashmap`?

Comment: Pranjal Doshi, hello good day sir, I am still in 1first year college in information technology I do not know that hashmap.